# How to give context to fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am really noob into kotlin and I was trying to implement applandeo calendar library o my project in kotlin. Everything works well if you use activities but when changing into fragments I don't know how to give context because "this" is not working as a Context. In te function openDatePicker() the first parameter should be the context, but no idea about how to get it.

Also I don't know if its possible to pass from a fragment to an activity. My project is structured as a main activity with a bottom navigation bar where every elements redirects to the fragment. This code is inside one of those fragments. Any help or idea will be great ! :)

class CalendarFragment : Fragment(), OnDayClickListener, OnSelectDateListener{

```
private lateinit var binding: CalendarViewFragmentBinding
private val notes = mutableMapOf<EventDay, String>()
private lateinit var appContext: Context

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {
    val context = this.context
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val calendar_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_view_fragment, container, false)
    binding = CalendarViewFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.fabButton.setOnClickListener { openDatePicker() }
    binding.calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(this)
    return calendar_view
}

private fun openDatePicker() {
    DatePickerBuilder(************, this)
        .pickerType(CalendarView.ONE_DAY_PICKER)
        .headerColor(R.color.md_theme_light_primary)
        .todayLabelColor(R.color.md_theme_light_primary)
        .selectionColor(R.color.md_theme_light_secondary)
        .dialogButtonsColor(R.color.md_theme_light_secondary)
        .build()
        .show()
}
```

I tried functions such as requireContext(), requireActivity(), requireContext().applicationContext, this.context, but no one working as I expect.

Comment: `requireContext()` is the way to do it. Don't try to store your `context` in a fragment class property, because that will leak the Activity instance. I don't understand what you mean by "pass from a fragment to an activity"

Comment: just use context simple no need to write like this val context = this.context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Fragment` is [attached to its context](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) when its `onAttach()` callback is invoked. This happens [before it reaches the `CREATED` lifecycle state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created):

> When your fragment reaches the `CREATED` state, it has been added to a `FragmentManager` and the `onAttach()` method has already been called.

What this means is that by the time `onCreate` is called (or any lifecycle callbacks after that, including `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`, `onStart` etc.) *your fragment will have a context*, and you can access it using `requireContext()`.

You could also use `getContext()`, which you can access as a property with `context`, but that returns *null* if the `Fragment` isn't associated with a context yet - meaning you have to null-check and handle that possibility. `requireContext()` will throw an exception if you don't have that context yet, but if you're making sure to only call it when the fragment is in the `CREATED` state (or later) then it will be safe, and you won't need to check the return value. This is the recommended way of doing things.

---

So as long as you're accessing the `Context` in a lifecycle callback like `onCreateView`, `requireContext()` will work - that's how you get the `Fragment`'s context. Because you're calling `openDatePicker` from inside `onCreateView`, you can just use `requireContext()` in that function - it's safe at that point!

But you can't define it as a normal top-level variable like this:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {
    var appContext: Context = requireContext()
}
```

because that variable is assigned *at construction time*, which happens way before the fragment reaches the `CREATED` state. You don't have access to the context at construction time, so any top-level stuff that requires it will end up throwing an exception. This goes for Activities too! That's why you have to assign stuff later, like in `onCreate` (and this is where `lateinit` comes in useful, you can have a top-level variable without having to assign it before you're ready)

And no, you can't pass `this` as a `Context` when you're in a `Fragment`, because a `Fragment` isn't a `Context`. It works for an `Activity` because that *is* a `Context` - to be more accurate it's able to *provide* one, but that only works after it's in the `CREATED` state. That's why you can get in trouble using it in top-level declarations like this

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity {
    val thing = ThingThatRequiresContext(this)
}
```

because like we just talked about, at construction time the `Activity` doesn't *have access to a context*, and the thing that requires it (if it tries to access it immediately) will end up throwing an exception. You see that error a lot, where an `Activity` can't be started because something like this is happening during initialisation.

Comment: Thanks man, I just override my onAttach function and declared there my context.
I have a lateinit var of type context at the beggining of the fragment class and then I give it value inside the onAttach function. That worked for me.
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        appContext = context
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just use it from Fragment. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext())

```kotlin
private fun openDatePicker() {
    DatePickerBuilder(requireContext(), this)
        .pickerType(CalendarView.ONE_DAY_PICKER)
        .headerColor(R.color.md_theme_light_primary)
        .todayLabelColor(R.color.md_theme_light_primary)
        .selectionColor(R.color.md_theme_light_secondary)
        .dialogButtonsColor(R.color.md_theme_light_secondary)
        .build()
        .show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi fragment has the context. You just have to use context instead of this, and if you want a `context` that is never null, use `requireContext()`